# Minecraft, mining a enchantment table

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I want to mine an enchantment table to pick it up do I need a silk touch pick or can I mine it with my hand or a pick or something?

Answer (score 1):

You can mine it with any pickaxe to obtain the item. Silk touch is not required. Mining it with your hand will destroy the table with no loot.

[Here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting_Table) is a source for it.

> Enchanting tables can be obtained by crafting or mining them. If mined
> without a pickaxe, it will drop nothing.